# SetTimeOut() in THREE JS

Tags: javascript, three.js

I realize a project for the master degree. 
I must create a three js space invaders game.

The project is well underway but i have a problem. My aliens ( THREE.Mesh object ) must be able to fire randomly. 
To carry out that, i've created a function which should draw a random number. This function works. 
The problem comes the animate() function. In fact i can't put a SetTimeOut() the animate() function.

The SetTimeOut() works the first time animate() is called but after there is no timer. The code executing continually without waiting the timer.

Maybe the problem coming because animate is continually called by requestAnimationFrame();

My code :

Index.html =>

```
if (!init())animate();

function animate(){
   requestAnimationFrame( animate );
   level1.animate();

   render();
}
```

Level.js =>

```
Level.prototype.animate = function()
{

 //Timer doesn't work
 var that = this;

 //Just a test with a simple console.log test
 setTimeout(function() { console.log("test"); },10000);*/

this.sky.rotation.x -=0.005;

this.spaceship.fire();
for (var i=0; i<this.ducks.length;i++)
{
   this.ducks[i].move();
    if (this.ducks[i].is_ready_to_fire())
        this.ducks[i].fire_if_ready();
}
```

};

With this example the program will wait 10 seconds the first time before print "test" and after the first call, print "test" without waiting.

Have you any ideas ?

Thank you very much.

Sorry for my poor english.

Comment: I think I see what's happening here: you're creating a new timer event on every `Level.prototype.animate()` call.

Comment: How to resolve that then ? Put the result into this.timer for example ?

Comment: And i printed the timer id and it's a different ID in all animate() call. So its a new timer everytime i think.

Answer (score 2):

The question if you need a timer for your purpose.

If I understand your problem correctly, you need the aliens to fire after a random amount of time.

If you don't care about the *exact* amount of time and only about the aliens shooting at random occasions, I'd use a counter on each alien to count the frames until it shoots.

So your code will look something like this:

```
var MAX_FRAMES_TO_WAIT = 600000;

Alien.prototype.init = function() {
 this.framesUntilFire = Math.round(Math.random() * MAX_FRAMES_TO_WAIT);
}

Alien.prototype.fireWhenReady = function() {
  if(--this.framesUntilFire === 0) {
    this.fire();
    this.framesUntilFire = Math.round(Math.random() * MAX_FRAMES_TO_WAIT);
  }
}

function animate() {
  requestAnimationFrame(animate);

  /* ... */

  for (var i=0; i<this.ducks.length;i++)
  {
    this.ducks[i].move();
    this.ducks[i].fireWhenReady();
  }
```

That should do the trick. Be aware that this will mean that the enemies fire quicker when the framerate is higher and slower when the framerate should drop.

You can counter that with counting the framerate as well and using it as a divider to level it out.

I hope that helped you a bit!

Answer (score 1):

You can avoid setting a new timer every frame by simply resetting a new timer once the previous one has finished.  A simple solution for this is recursive:

```
Level.prototype.fireDelayed = function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
        if (!this.currentLevel) {
            return;
        }

        this.fireDelayed();
        this.fire();
    }.bind(this), Math.random() * 1000);
};
```

It simply stops firing if the level is no longer the `currentLevel`.

Does that make sense?

Comment: Thank you but Still doesn't work. It's very strange.